# How to use custom validator in service layer in Yii2?

Tags: validation, yii2

In my `yii2-advanced` template project I have a custom `Validator` class  that validates `email` from Registration form.

```
<?php

namespace common\components\validators;

use yii\validators\Validator;
use common\models\BlackListEmails;
use common\models\BlackListDomains;
use common\models\BlackListDomainsPart;

class EmailBlackListsValidator extends Validator
{
    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        if(strpos($model->$attribute, '+') !== false){
            $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'Error email - "plus sign"');
        }

        $emailDomain =  explode('@', $model->$attribute)[1];

        if(
            BlackListDomains::find()->where(['domain' => strtolower($emailDomain)])->exists()
            || BlackListEmails::find()->where(['email' => strtolower($model->$attribute)])->exists()
        )
            {
            $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'The email or domain in a black list');
        }
    }
}
```

It works good but now I need to make the same validation for `email` not inside a controller but inside one of services. 
The only difference is validator should throw `Exception` instead of `add error` to model.

Is it possible to use this `Validator` class for this purpose? Or maybe I should use `yii\base\DynamicModel` and add validator class dynamically with `addRule` method? Or maybe there is a proper ways to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are looking to use the same validator class without any change in code then `DynamicModel` will do it fine.

Comment: As I noticed the only difference is validator should throw Exception instead of add error to model.

Comment: you can check for `$model->hasError()` and throw and exception your self , whats the problem in it

Comment: thanks, I already made it in this way: `$dynamicModel = (new yii\base\DynamicModel(['email' => $form->email]))
                ->addRule('email', EmailBlackListsValidator::class);
            if (!$dynamicModel->validate()){
                throw new ClientException($dynamicModel->errors['email'][0]);  
            }`

Comment: yeah that should work correctly